# Symfony Panther How to check a checkbox?

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, testing, symfony-panther

I'm trying this code to check a html input checkbox, but it's not working:

```
$this->client->findElement(WebDriverBy::cssSelector('.checkbox_additional_field_assign'))->sendKeys(true);
```

The checkbox:

```
<input name="additionalField" value="14" class="checkbox_additional_field_assign" type="checkbox">
```

Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I find out the way:

```
$this->client->executeScript("document.querySelector('.checkbox_additional_field_assign').click()");
```